# Numbers similar to Ramanujan's taxi cab number

Tags: number-theory

Ramanujan's taxi cab number being the smallest number expressible in two different ways as sum of $2$ cubes. makes one wonder about :

1. Whether there are numbers expressible of sum of $2$ different numbers in $3$ different ways. ( or $n$ different ways )
2. Whether there exists numbers powers $k$ of $n$ different numbers in $j$ different ways, for what $j$,$k$,$n$ such numbers exists and besides using computers can some examples be found by reasoning rather than just trial and error?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_taxicab_number seems to answer all my questions.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A011541

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_taxicab_number

Comment: @mathlove-I think there are two such numbers which can be written in this way-one is 1729,which is the result of both $10^3+9^3$ & $12^3+1^3$,in the similar way we can write the other number 635318657 which is the result of both $133^4+134^4$ & $158^4+59^4$,

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518859/numbers-similar-to-ramanujans-taxi-cab-number